# Where can I find a summary of what was legislated over today?

Tags: united-states, congress

Are there any resources to see what was voted on/proposed each day? I'm not so much interested in why/who voted for what, but a fact sheet of the events for the day would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE. In which country? All over the world? For what?

Comment: United States specifically. I updated the flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main US Congress website publishes a Daily Digest searchable by date here: https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record

There are lists for chamber actions, committee meetings, etc, with additional links for each item if you want more detail on them.